# Maya MEL script pass command with string array parameter to evalEcho

Tags: arrays, echo, eval, maya, mel

How to pass a command with a string array parameter to `evalEcho` in MEL? The code below doesn't work (just an example), `$list` must have been declared to work, but this is done in `createList`.

```mel
global proc string[] returnList(string $list[]) {
    return $list;
}

global proc createList() {
    string $list[];

    $list[0] = "Hello";
    $list[1] = "World";

    evalEcho "returnList $list";
}

createList();
```

Terminal:

`// Error: Line 11.17: "$list" is an undeclared variable. //`

For some reason the next code works as expected:

```mel
global proc string[] returnList(string $list[]) {
    return $list;
}

string $list[];

$list[0] = "Hello";
$list[1] = "World";

evalEcho "returnList $list";
```

Answer (score 1):

or put them inside too....

```
global proc string[] returnList(string $list[]) {
    return $list;
}

global proc createList() {
    evalEcho "string $list[]";

    evalEcho "$list[0] = \"Hello\"";
    evalEcho "$list[1] = \"World\"";

    evalEcho "returnList $list";
}

createList();
```

Comment: @Danilo (I can't add a comment under your post) why your version is working - because of encapsulation(you're decalred varialbes outside the scope as evalEcho do).

Comment: Why my version is work - I put variables outside the scope by evaluating them with eval. You can get same result if you declare your variable in `createList` as global (`global string $list[];`)

Answer (score 0):

This code is supposed to work the way you expected:

```
global proc string[] returnList(string $list[]) {
    return $list;
}

global proc createList() {
    string $list[];
    $list = stringToStringArray("Hello, World!", " ");

    evalEcho( "\n" + "//" + " " + $list[0] + " " + $list[1] + " " );
}

createList();
```

[image]